# How can I limit the number of instances of an application being run in a single Windows session?

Tags: windows, excel, vba

Some time ago on I asked about [limiting the number of instances of Excel being run concurrently in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836291/how-can-i-run-an-excel-add-in-on-mutliple-instances-of-excel-exe).

Thanks to the help I got on StackOverflow.com I was able to put together the following function that shuts down any instance of Excel that is launched if there is already another instance of Excel running.

```
Private Function KillDuplicateProcesses() As Boolean

    Dim objWMIService As Object
    Dim colItems As Variant
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim intCount As Integer

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    For Each objItem In colItems
        intCount = intCount + Abs(LCase(objItem.Name) = "excel.exe")
        If intCount > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Excel is already running." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "To open a file use " & IIf(Application.Version >= 12, "Office Button", "File") & " > Open (Ctrl + O).", vbCritical
            KillDuplicateProcesses = True
            Application.Quit
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

The problem is that if a user is logged onto a remote desktop session as an administrator, that user account can see all of the other users and the processes that they have running. So if another user is logged onto the same machine and is running Excel, the function counts those instances as well and shuts down the instance of Excel that has just been launched.

I need to limit the scope of that function to the currently running session. According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) there is a class property called SessionID. Can I use that property and compare it against the current session's ID to limit what the function counts, or is there a better way to do it?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

*Below is the solution code per Tim's suggestion. Note I am comparing the GetOwner properties against Environ UserName and UserDomain. Environ is considered unreliable because it can be changed by the user.*

```
Private Function KillDuplicateProcesses() As Boolean

    Dim objWMIService As Object
    Dim colItems As Variant
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim strProcessUser As Variant
    Dim strProcessDomain As Variant

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'excel.exe'")

    If colItems.Count > 1 Then

        For Each objItem In colItems

            strProcessUser = ""
            strProcessDomain = ""
            objItem.GetOwner strProcessUser, strProcessDomain
            If IsNull(strProcessUser) Then strProcessUser = ""
            If IsNull(strProcessDomain) Then strProcessDomain = ""

            intCount = intCount + Abs(strProcessUser = Environ("UserName") _
                And strProcessDomain = Environ("UserDomain"))
            If intCount > 1 Then
                MsgBox "You cannot run more than one instance of Excel while iTools is activated." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "To open a file use " & IIf(Application.Version >= 12, "Office Button", "File") & " > Open (Ctrl + O).", vbCritical
                KillDuplicateProcesses = True
                Application.Quit
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'get process owner username and domain
Dim strUser, strDomain
objItem.getOwner strUser, strDomain
MsgBox strUser & ", " & strDomain
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim. I'm trying that and comparing against Environ.UserName and Environ.UserDomainName. Seems to be working but I need to test a little bit more.

Comment: Per your suggestion I posted the _air code_ (untested) as an update to my question.

Comment: Your suggestion works, although calling GetOwner for every process is very slow, so I limited the Win32_Process query by adding a where clause to only return processes with Name = "excel.exe" which dramatically improves performance. I put the solution code in the updated question. Thanks Tim.